# rails test fails for testing custom cache store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, caching, automated-tests

in Rails 4.2 I'm extending `ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore` to make my own that backs up values to the database. This is what it looks like so far:

```
class FileStoreWithDbBackup < ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore

  def write(name, value, options = nil)
    super(name, value, options)
    Rails.logger.debug('write!')
    if options[:backup]
      backup = CacheBackup.find_or_create_by(name: name)
      backup.value = value
      if options[:expires_in]
        backup.expires = options[:expires_in].from_now
      end
      backup.save
    end
  end

end
```

When I use it from the console it seems to work fine, but when I try it in the testing environment the superclass functionality works (it caches and restores values) but the database backup doesn't work. Is there something about the testing environment config that I need to change?

I tried setting `config.action_controller.perform_caching` to `true` but that didn't work.

Here is my test file (which uses minitest-spec syntax):

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'file_store_with_db_backup'

describe FileStoreWithDbBackup do

  let(:store) {FileStoreWithDbBackup.new 'tmp/cache/'}
  let(:key) {'data key'}
  let(:payload) {'data value'}

  it 'caches data' do
    store.fetch(key){ payload }
    fetched = store.fetch(key) do
      fail('regenerating value')
    end
    _(fetched).must_equal payload
  end

  it 'backs up to db when asked' do
    store.fetch(key, expires_in: 1.day, backup: true) { payload }
    backup = CacheBackup.find_by_name key
    _(backup.value).must_equal payload
    _(backup.expires).must_be_close_to 1.day.from_now
  end

end
```

The first test passes, the second test bottoms out when it can't find the `CacheBackup`.

**UPDATE**

when I call the `write` method directly in the test it works, but the `fetch` method of the store's superclass should call the `write` method if it doesn't find the key and a block is provided. This works from the rails console, but not in the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that the content of the cache (in this case being in files stored on my local filesystem) was being persisted between tests, and indeed, between runs of the test suite.

The `fetch` method of the cache store's superclass wasn't calling the write method because it was finding the entry in the cache.

So it was necessary for me to clear the cache out before each test using a `before` method in the test file

```
before do
  store.clear
end
```